# Issue happening when creating a trigger in Oracle SQL (Online)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm facing a problem while creating a trigger in Oracle SQL (Online). Please find the issue(s) with the code.

These are my codes.

customers table code:

```
CREATE TABLE customers( 
    cusid INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    cusnm VARCHAR(10), 
    cusadd VARCHAR(10) 
)
```

audits table code:

```
CREATE TABLE audits( 
    table_name VARCHAR2(255), 
    transaction_name VARCHAR2(10), 
    by_user VARCHAR2(30), 
    transaction_date DATE 
)
```

Trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customers_audit_trg
AFTER
UPDATE OR DELETE
ON customers
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    tx VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
    --determine the transaction type
    tx := CASE
        WHEN UPDATING THEN 'UPDATE'
        WHEN DELETING THEN 'DELETE'
    END;
    
    --insert a row into the audit table
    INSERT INTO audits(table_name, transaction_name, by_user, transaction_date)
    VALUES('customers', tx, USER, SYSDATE)
END;
/
```

Errors:

```
Errors: TRIGGER CUSTOMERS_AUDIT_TRG
Line/Col: 2/8 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
   double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
   character nchar
```

Comment: The error is different and at different line. Please check [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91d49cf81ff6c57950136ad7733b0520). After I add a semicolon after insert, there are no more errors

Comment: If you are having issues with your code, please explain what those problems are. We can't read your screen, or mind for that matter

Comment: Found the error also the solution! Thank you for the link @astentx.

Comment: I'm sorry if I made any mistakes. I'll be more careful when asking a question @HoneyBadger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a semicolon missing issue.

```
    --insert a row into the audit table
    INSERT INTO audits(table_name, transaction_name, by_user, transaction_date)
    VALUES('customers', tx, USER, SYSDATE);
```